# How can i test my site on iPad without having one?

Tags: testing

i recieved comments that one of my [web sites (tumblr theme)](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/11037) is crashing on iPad. i dont have an iPad so i wonder how will you test your site on iPad, iPhone or any other smart phone for that matter?

Comment: (I'm sure you've done this...) Have you tested your website in desktop Safari? If it crashes there, then you don't necessarily need an iPad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on a Mac, you can get the iOS SDK 4.0.1, which includes an iPhone/iPad simulator. You have to register as a developer, but it says you can for free. Note, I don't have a Mac, so I haven't tried this myself.

[iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action)

EDIT: [Here is a direct link to the registration page.](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register)

Comment: Note SDK 4 requires OS X 10.6 on your desktop Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.ipadpeek.com will work for you. There is a way to test iPad apps in the new iPad SDK, but I'm not sure if it's a full-fledged emulator. It may or may not let you go into safari and try out your website, though I think it's unlikely.

Comment: ipadpeek.com really only displays your website in a browser the same resolution as an iPad, it won't help him figure out why his site is crashing.

Comment: yes i tried iPadPeek b4 i posted here actually. it didnt crash :) i guess @phoffer is right

Comment: if you check your user agent in ipadpeek, it returns whatever browser you are using on your comp. That is the best giveaway, but I believe I read it somewhere too.