# how can i check the my site on IPAD safari?

Tags: ipad, macos, safari

i have a client site [www.noozhoo.com](http://www.noozhoo.com) which worked fine on browser in PC or laptop but from client i get the point that its site crash in when open in IPAD on safari browser.My concern is how can i check my site on IPAD because i dont have and i use one online simulator for IPAD and my website works perfect in that simulator .Is there can be issue related to memory or hardware  of IPAD or something  else .please guide me .
i also go through this link but not helping me. [test site on ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323635/how-can-i-test-my-site-on-ipad-without-having-one)
thanks buddy

Comment: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.noozhoo.com/ from frame with URL http://player.i checked that error and i dont get any solution to remove this error. but as far as i checked there is also identical error on espn.com so is this site also crashing on IPAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these issues that I found when trying out your site. Fix them and then try it on iPad. The top one is most likely to be the cause.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.noozhoo.com/ from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/24837480?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
controls.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
border.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
loading_background.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
indicator.gif
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cross-poppup.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I found them using the developer tools console in Chrome.

Comment: i will try to fix them and if it will help i will mark you as answer.

Comment: Okay, these errors are important to fix anyway, even if it doesn't fix your iPad bug. If you still have problems with your iPad, check out this post - http://www.blog.cordslatton.com/2010/11/debugging-ios-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone/ I found it really useful.

Comment: i checked that error and i dont get any solution to remove this error. but as far as i checked there is also identical error on espn.com so is this site also crashing on IPAD.

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.blog.cordslatton.com/2010/11/debugging-ios-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone/